# I don't want to show the HTML file name as the home page, such as stackoverflow.com, instead of stackoverflow.com/home

Tags: html, file, .htaccess

Using htaccess I was able to hide the file extensions, making it /home instead of /home.html. However, for the homepage, I would like to hide the file name altogether, for example stackoverflow.com, instead of stackoverflow.com/home. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to look into using a [rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

From Wikipedia:

> A **rewrite engine** is software that
>   modifies a web URL's appearance (**URL
>   rewriting**). Rewritten URLs (sometimes
>   known as **short** or **fancy** URLs) are used
>   to provide shorter and more
>   relevant-looking links to web pages.
>   The technique adds a degree of
>   separation between the files used to
>   generate a web page and the URL that
>   is presented to the world.

More specifically, it depends on the web server you're using. Here's a guide to [URL Rewriting in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), for example.

Answer (score 1):

See [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex):

```
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the home page index.html, then it will display as the default for / (given normal apache rules)